# Filter many-to-many relationship by user and show in template Django

Tags: python, django, templates, model, m2m

I'm stucked with a problem. I'm developing e-Learning application and have this model (simplified for better understanding):

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    enrolled = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), through='Enrol', related_name="course_enrolled")
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="course_teacher")


class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Classe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), through='ClassCompleted', related_name="classes_completed")


class Enrol(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class ClassCompleted(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())
    classe = models.ForeignKey(Classe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My View for the Course page. This page has to show the Sections and Classes.

```
@login_required
def ead_course(request, course_id):
    try:
         course = Course.objects.get(id=course_id)
    except Course.DoesNotExist:
         raise Http404

     # Check if student is enroll or is a teacher
    if request.user.course_enrolled.filter(id=course_id).exists() or course.teacher.id is request.user.id:
        return render(request, 'ead/ead_course.html', {'course': course})

    return HttpResponse("Without permission")
```

And finally my template ead_course.html:

```
{% for section in course.section_set.all %}
    {{ section.name }}
    {% for class in section.classe_set.all %}
        {{ class.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Everything is fine until now, I'm showing for user all the sections and the classes.

The big problem is: I need to check if a student completed some class, so I created a Many to many table ClassCompleted, to show to student his progress, but I'm having a hard time to show this in template.

I need the progress was separated by section, so each section will show how many classes a student completed of a total. Like this:

### Module 1 - 2/4 Classes completed

- Class 1 (Completed)
- Class 2 (Completed)
- Class 3
- Class 4

### Module 2 - 0/1 Classes completed

- Class 1

I tried this by creating filter in views and creating template tags but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to filter all courses completed by user, and interate in a forloop with all courses

```
@login_required
def ead_course(request, course_id):
     try:
         course = Course.objects.get(id=course_id)
     except Course.DoesNotExist:
         raise Http404

     # Check if student is enroll or is a teacher
     if request.user.course_enrolled.filter(id=course_id).exists() or course.teacher.id is request.user.id:
          courses_completed = ClassCompleted.objects.filter(student=request.user, completed=True)
          return render(request, 'ead/ead_course.html', {'course': course, 'courses_completed': courses_completed})

    return HttpResponse("Without permission")
```

and in template:

```
{% for section in course.section_set.all %}
    {{ section.name }}
    {% for class in section.classe_set.all %}
        {{ class.name }}
        {% for completed in courses_completed %}
            {% if class.id == completed.classe.id %}
            <p>Completou</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works, but not looks like a good way to do, I think that can exist a better solution to filter the completed class by sections,I will try create some templatetags

Answer (score 0):

I can achieve this with a filter template tag filtering the completed classes by section and user. I don't know if this is a best practice but works!

```
from django import template

from ..models import ClassCompleted

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def completed_class_for_section_for_user(section, user):
    return ClassCompleted.objects.filter(classe__section=section, student=user, completed=True)
```

And using in template:

```
{% for section in course.section_set.all %}
    {{ section.name }}
    {% for classe in section.classe_set.all %}
        {{ classe.name }}
        {% for completed_classe in section|completed_class_for_section_for_user:user %}
            {% if completed_classe.classe.id == classe.id %}
                Completed                
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If someone has a better solution, please, post here.